# How can Google WorkSpace Shared Drives be seen by third-party iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, google, google-apps

First, this question is not about "Shared Folders", but "Google WorkSpace **Shared Drives**".

Google WorkSpace administrators set up "**Shared Drives**" for each department.  Whether on Linux or Windows PCs, staff automatically see and use these shared drives for things like shared password databases.  They find it relatively easy on the PC.

The [Google "Drive"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) app itself on iPhone has no problem seeing the "**Shared Drives**" and works perfectly.

[image: Google Drive APP on iOS iPhone showing "Shared Drives"]

The problem is third party apps do not see "Shared Drives".  Not Keepassium, not StrongBox, not KeePassTouch, ... nothing.   The shortcut trick results in multiple versions of the same file nightmare - especially for password databases.  Is there some configuration setting that be set?  Otherwise, what is the purpose of "Shared Drives" on the iPhone if they cannot be used?

Comment: Does google not make a file provider app like Microsoft and others do? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider Then the google files will be available on the native files app and for other iOS uses.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran in this issue ("Shared Drives" tab does not show in iOS Google Drive app).  After consulting the IT, I realized that it is only happening on some of my iOS devices.  (iOS devices of other people have the tab.)  I also can see the "Shared Drives" tab on a new iOS device of mine.  So this seems to be a client-side issue.

Then I managed to resolve the issue by reinstalling the quad in the Google office suite: Drive, Docs, Sheets, and Slides.  All of them need to be uninstalled before reinstallation.

Merely reinstalling Google Drive does not solve the issue.  Log-out and re-log-in does not solve the issue.

Comment: Interesting, I can now use KeePassium to export an existing password database to a Google Workplace Shared Drive, but still cannot open an existing password db on a Shared Drive.

Comment: My problem is not with the Google Drive app itself but apps developed outside of Google that need to access Google Workspace Shared Drives.

Comment: The screenshot in the question had made it clear that the Google Drive App itself could see ( and read / write )  various Shared Drives under the "Shared Drives" tab.  However, i now notice the screenshot is very blurry :( .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Workplace administrator has restricted the access to work-related Google services from unmanaged (personal) apps. Which does make sense security-wise.

The solution would be to install your favorite KeePass flavor as a work app. To do so, your Workplace administrator should [add the app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328701?hl=en&ref_topic=4651167#add) to the Google Admin console. (Admin Console home → Apps → Web and mobile apps → Add app → … → Make this a managed app.)

*Disclaimers: I am the author of KeePassium. The answer is purely theoretical, based on some understanding of app management and Google documentation.*

Comment: has looked promising.   Have done everything but make it a managed App because if i turn that on, people get locket out of their accounts in 24 hours if they do not sign in or something like that.   Will have to find a way to test and research some more.

Comment: Added KeePassium as a Managed App.  Resynced "Google Device Policy", but it still does not see "Shared Drives."  I may not have done this correctly.  Would really like this to work.